# Font name appears as gibberish in font manager or any font selection menu

Tags: fonts

I downloaded the Epson japanese fonts however they contain non-latin characters in their name and for some reason they render as giberish. Is there a setting I'm missing? In windows I think you had system wide locale.

This is the output of the locale

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

These are the fonts I installed from the ttf files.

```
"EPSON 行書体Ｍ",
"EPSON 正楷書体Ｍ",
"EPSON 教科書体Ｍ",
"EPSON 太明朝体Ｂ",
"EPSON 太行書体Ｂ",
"EPSON 丸ゴシック体Ｍ"
```

*note
I opened the font in a font editor to clarify myself and indeed the field from 'Name for Humans' doesn't get converted properly from EPSON çsèëëÃÇl to EPSON 太行書体B
[image]

I'm using ubuntu 20.04
[image]

Comment: You-re missing those fonts, obviously. You can easily install support for Japanese or Chinese simply by adding those languages in "Region and Language". It installs both the spelling tools and basic fonts required.

Comment: I have installed the fonts among others. Also have the language installed.

Comment: The `locale` output looks good, and UTF-8 is consistently enabled (which it should be). Possibly those font names are written using some non-UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes. Just changed the local LANG from en_us to ja_JP.utf8 which in turned changed the whole interface of ubuntu to japanese not quite what I was looking for :D But sadly the font names still rendered as giberish. Quite bizare. Yes the fonts are shiftjis

Comment: @C.Astraea: OTOH, does it matter in practice, i.e. is the font useful for rendering Japanese content? And another question, btw: Did you try to use the Japanese font which is installed by default, i.e. the `fonts-noto-cjk` package?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I think it's not a big deal :) I'm trying to install as many japanese fonts as possible for running a tampermonkey user script https://gist.github.com/obskyr/9f3c77cf6bf663792c6e#file-jitai-user-js . I was thinking the script might have some problem if it can't reference the font name exactly as it is.  I'll just remove these Epson fonts for now and stick to the ones with latin alphabet names. Yes I have those fonts as well.

Comment: Based on [the notes on the Epson download page](https://www.epson.jp/dl_soft/readme/27767.htm) those fonts are very much Windows-only. This is most likely because the internal encoding of the .ttf is either ShiftJIS or the horrible ISO-8859-1-JP-MS. One possible option is to use an online font conversion service to take the original and output a UTF-8-compliant version of the font ...